# Using struct name as a function

Tags: c++, function, data-structures, struct

I'm trying to understand what the following line does:

```
BStats stats = BStats();
```

The struct is defined as follows:

```
struct BStats
{
    unsigned a;
    unsigned b;

    BStats& operator+=(const BStats& rhs)
    {
        this->a += rhs.a;
        this->b += rhs.b;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

But I have no idea about what this line does. Is it calling the default constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `BStats()` is described in the standard in 5.2.3/2:

> The expression T(), where T is a simple-type-specifier (7.1.5.2) for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates an rvalue of the specified type, which is value-initialized.

That is, the expression creates an *rvalue* of `Bstats` type that is *value-initialized*. In your particular case, *value-initialization* means that the two members of the `BStats` struct will be set to zero.

Note that this is different than the behavior of calling the *default-constructor* that is mentioned in other answers, as the default constructor will not guarantee that the members are set to 0.

Comment: @basak you'll be surprised.... But `BStats stats();` does not call any constructor, it does not even declare an object of type `BStats` but rather *declares* a function that takes no arguments and returns a `BStats`... Google for *most-vexing-parse*

Answer (score 0):

Just like any class, a struct has a default constructor automatically created by the compiler. In your case, BStats() simply calls the default constructor, although the explicit call is useless.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ Classes and Structs are almost the same (the difference is that C++ structs are classes with public as the default attribute where a class's is private) so it's like calling a constructor.